# How to reduce the size of an iOS app with vector images?

Tags: ios, xcode, svg, app-store

I had a 25 mb app (size in store).  After adding 2500 svg images to assets I got 77-120 mb size depending on the device. (I determined the size using this [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing-your-app-s-size))

My svg images are 42 mb. I compressed them to 18 mb and replaced in the project. But the size didn't change.
I also tried to check the box 'Preserve vector data' (the size even increased), tried the modes 'Single scale' and 'Individual scales' - no result

What kind of problem could this be?

svg example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="640" height="640" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="ID100">
    <circle cx="320.0" cy="320.0" r="319.0" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1"/>
    <line x1="320.0" y1="160.0" x2="320.0" y2="608.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="160.0" y1="320.0" x2="480.0" y2="320.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="304.0" y1="315.2" x2="304.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="304.0" x2="324.8" y2="304.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="336.0" y1="315.2" x2="336.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="288.0" y1="312.0" x2="288.0" y2="328.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="288.0" x2="328.0" y2="288.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="352.0" y1="312.0" x2="352.0" y2="328.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="272.0" y1="315.2" x2="272.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="272.0" x2="324.8" y2="272.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="368.0" y1="315.2" x2="368.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="256.0" y1="312.0" x2="256.0" y2="328.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="256.0" x2="328.0" y2="256.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="384.0" y1="312.0" x2="384.0" y2="328.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="240.0" y1="315.2" x2="240.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="240.0" x2="324.8" y2="240.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="400.0" y1="315.2" x2="400.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="224.0" y1="312.0" x2="224.0" y2="328.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="224.0" x2="328.0" y2="224.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="416.0" y1="312.0" x2="416.0" y2="328.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="208.0" y1="315.2" x2="208.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="208.0" x2="324.8" y2="208.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="432.0" y1="315.2" x2="432.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="192.0" y1="312.0" x2="192.0" y2="328.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="192.0" x2="328.0" y2="192.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="448.0" y1="312.0" x2="448.0" y2="328.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="176.0" y1="315.2" x2="176.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="176.0" x2="324.8" y2="176.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="464.0" y1="315.2" x2="464.0" y2="324.8" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="336.0" x2="324.8" y2="336.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="352.0" x2="328.0" y2="352.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="368.0" x2="324.8" y2="368.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="384.0" x2="328.0" y2="384.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="400.0" x2="324.8" y2="400.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="416.0" x2="328.0" y2="416.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="432.0" x2="324.8" y2="432.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="448.0" x2="328.0" y2="448.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="464.0" x2="324.8" y2="464.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="480.0" x2="328.0" y2="480.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="496.0" x2="324.8" y2="496.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="512.0" x2="328.0" y2="512.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="528.0" x2="324.8" y2="528.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="544.0" x2="328.0" y2="544.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="560.0" x2="324.8" y2="560.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="312.0" y1="576.0" x2="328.0" y2="576.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <line x1="315.2" y1="592.0" x2="324.8" y2="592.0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <rect x="480.0" y="313.6" width="161.0" height="12.799999999999955" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <rect x="-1.0" y="313.6" width="161.0" height="12.799999999999955" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <rect x="313.6" y="608.0" width="12.799999999999955" height="33.0" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
    <rect x="313.6" y="-1.0" width="12.799999999999955" height="161.0" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are they actual vector shapes (path, rect, circle), or are they base64 encoded raster images? Please post some sample files so we know what you're looking at.

Comment: @zombiedoctor
Sample
https://file.io/fEcv437BwlB9

Comment: What is the minimum iOS version of your app?

Comment: @zombiedoctor 13.0